# Splitting a List of Strings into a List of Characters C#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of strings called ls that looks something like this 01101101 01101101 01111101 00101000

I would like to convert the list of strings into a list of characters. The current list is a list of 8 bit numbers. I would like the list to signify the end of each number I hope this makes sense.

What I have tried:

```
 List<string> ls = new List<string>(); //Currently holds the eight bit numbers
 List<char> splitList = new List<char>();

            foreach (string s in ls)
            {

                splitList = splitList.ToCharArray();
            }
```

This currently throws a Char[] to char exception, but I believe this way would not signify the end of each number

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? It seems that you are trying to solve the problem X with an Y solution that is not the most appropriate.

Comment: Provide an example and purpose, so that's its clear

Comment: i think its fair to say he wants to convert base2 strings into ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ here

**For example**

```
List<Char> lsChar = lsString.SelectMany(s => s.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Need to add `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: Your answer is good but you are not signifying the end of each number in the new list lsChar.

Answer (score 0):

a `string` it’s essentially an enumerable of characters, so you should just add the string itself as a collection of characters (so you should use `AddRange()` for that).

```
foreach (string s in ls)
{
    splitList.AddRange(s);
}
```